# Replace text in between certain pattern in UNIX

Tags: shell-script, postgresql

I want to replace the Millisecond field from file with ":" patter to "." pattern.

```
Input:-
Jun 12 2018  3:33:49:000PM
Jun 12 2018  3:33:49:850AM

Desired Output:-
Jun 12 2018  3:33:49.000PM
Jun 12 2018  3:33:49.850AM
```

I have tried below Sed command from my side but did not get 100% result from it, below is my SED command:-

```
cat input.txt | sed 's/\(|\|^\|[A-Z]\)\([^|\]*\):\([0-9]\+\)\(AM\|PM\)\(|\|$\)/\1\2.\3 \4\5/g;s/"/ /g;s/:000/.000 /g' >output.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sed -E 's/:([0-9]+[AP]M$)/.\1/'
```

I haven't tried to figure out what's wrong with your regex, but personally I would not bother matching the beginning of the line unless you have to. It should also be quicker to just match the end of the line.

Comment: I Have tried above command but still giving me old output                                                           Jun 11 2018  6:05:48:000AM

Comment: Do you have Windows style line endings in your file (CRLF)? You can convert the file to UNIX style with a tool like `fromdos` or modify the above regexp by removing the match against line ending (`$`).

Answer (score 0):

In the end, you want to replace the third colon with a dot:

```
sed 's/:/./3' input.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried below sed command and it solved my purpose

sed -e 's/([A-Z][a-z]{2}[ ]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}[ ]{1,2}[0-9]{4}[ ]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}):([0-9]{3}[A,P]M)/\1.\2/g'